# Vaadin Desktop Notifications

Tags: vaadin

Is there any support for html5 browser 'desktop notifications' in Vaadin? I've looked for this and can't find anything specific.

I've tried something like this with no luck.

```
        JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
            "if (window.webkitNotifications) {" +
                    "if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) { // 0 is PERMISSION_ALLOWED" +
            "    window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(" +
            "        'icon.png', 'Notification Title', 'Notification content...');" +
            "  } else {\n" +
            "    window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();" +
            "  } " +
            "} else { " +
            "   console.log('no notifications')" +
            "}");
```

Using vaadin 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried with the old api, it hasn't been supported for many versions. The [new api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API) should work:

```
  JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
        "  if (!(\"Notification\" in window)) { " +
        "    alert(\"This browser does not support system notifications\"); " +
        "  } else if (Notification.permission === \"granted\") { " +
        "    new Notification(\"Hi there!\"); " +
        "  } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') { " +
        "    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) { " +
        "      if (permission === \"granted\") { " +
        "        Notification(\"Hi there!\"); " +
        "      } " +
        "    }); " +
        "  } "
  );
```

Can't say this is a good way to do it though.

There is a plugin for vaadin 7 https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/webnotifications you can adopt it to 8. Or create a [JavaScript component](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html) or at at least a [JavaScript function](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-javascript.html) that will make  using it easier.